# Burger in responsive menu moves when clicked

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive, hamburger-menu

When my site goes to a smaller sign the menu goes to two parts a "home" button and a burger button for the rest of the menu. All works but when I click the menu it moves a little but it is very annoying. I searched and found one post with the same question but the buildup was completely different and not suitable for my needs.
I hope someone can help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-t0-fit=no">

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="title.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css">
      <title></title>
    </head>

      <!-- title of the website with link -->
      <a href="error404.html">
      <div class="title">B</div>
      </a>
      <!-- vertical navigation menu -->
      <body>

      <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
              <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
              <a href="error404.html">News</a>
              <a href="error404.html">Shop</a>
              <a href="error404.html">Contact</a>
              <a href="#about">About</a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                  <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
              </a>
      </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    &nbsp;

      <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
          x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
          x.className = "topnav";
        }
      }
      </script>

      </body>

</html>
```

menu.css

```
.topnav {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.topnav a {
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  color: black;
  width: 20%;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.icon {
  margin: 1em;
  width: 3px;
}

.icon:after,
.icon:before,
.icon div {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 7px 0;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.icon:hover:before {
  transform: translateY(12px) rotate(135deg);
}

.icon:hover:after {
  transform: translateY(-12px) rotate(-135deg);
}

.icon:hover div {
  transform: scale(0);
}



@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;

  }
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue without your CSS ("menu.css" and possible "title.css").

Comment: Sorry I totally forgot, the title.css is not needed (I think)

Comment: Tested on a Mac (10.15.5) in Chrome (83), Edge (83), FireFox (78) and Safari (13.1.1) and I don't experience the menu moving. Note that you wrote `shrink-t0-fit` (a zero instead of the letter "O").

Comment: I don't get it when I make my screen smaller the burger appears but if I click it it (the burger) goes down a little. I tested it on safari and in chrome both the same.

Comment: Is the code in your example exactly the same as the code on the page you are testing?